# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para usar un componente en una nueva pestaña?

Tags: angular, rutas

Tengo mi `app.component.html` de esta forma:

```
<router-outlet>
    <app-nav-bar> </app-nav-bar>
    <app-slider> </app-slider>
    <app-body> </app-body>
    <app-asesores> </app-asesores>
    <app-emprendimiento> </app-emprendimiento>
    <app-aliados> </app-aliados>
    <app-footer> </app-footer> 
</router-outlet>
```

Tengo un enlace de esta forma:

```
<div class="mr-2"> <a [routerLink]="['/franquiciaSea']" target="_blank" >Franquicia Sea</a> </div>
```

Ya hice la importación del módulo `Router` y todo lo que necesito en el `app.component.ts` y agregué la ruta así:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'franquiciaSea', component: FranquiciaSeaComponent }

];
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que al hacer clic en el enlace, me abra una nueva pestaña con solamente el contenido de la componente `FranquiciaSea`, actualmente lo que hace es cargar todo lo que está en el `app.component.html` y al final agrega el componente `franquiciaSea`. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: el routerlink se perdera en el tab , que tal si agregas tu url `<a href="tuservidotr/franquiciaSea" target="_blank">` recuerda que el routerLink es de angular con el codigo ya cargado en la web, probablemente falle no tengo documentacion como mostrartelo

Answer (score 2):

En tu app.component veo que tienes tus rutas así.

```
<router-outlet>
<app-nav-bar> </app-nav-bar>
<app-slider> </app-slider>
<app-body> </app-body>
<app-asesores> </app-asesores>
<app-emprendimiento> </app-emprendimiento>
<app-aliados> </app-aliados>
<app-footer> </app-footer>
```

Deberías un archivo de rutas app.routing.module.ts y así declaras los path a los que harás link desde el home o donde quieras llamarlo.

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu explicación. Podrías darme un ejemplo si no es mucha molestia? Ya casi estoy por utilizar href y colocar las páginas en una carpeta porque no he podido resolver.

Comment: Primero lo primero, tienes tu app.routing.module.ts?

Comment: Eso no lo tengo, solo definición las rutas en el app.module.ts e importe el modulo route.

Comment: Te dejo este blog para que veas de que trata

Comment: https://blog.ng-classroom.com/blog/angular/Angular-Routing/

Comment: Estoy siguiendo ese tutorial pero en el app.routing.module me muestra este error:  ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(5,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FranquiciaSeaComponent'.  y no se por que, ya que en el app.routing.module tengo esto: const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'franquiciaSea', component: FranquiciaSeaComponent }
];

Comment: Importaste el app routing module al app module?